# How to recreate a 3d-effect carousel while allowing native scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-animations, carousel

I've created a carousel using pure CSS that has a 3d effect, and it works well.

However, it uses radio inputs to toggle which item is 'active', which means it doesn't allow scrolling. As it will only ever have 3 items, this isn't a big deal on desktop.

On mobile though, being able to scroll a carousel feels like a must - users will expect it to work.

I've looked into using scroll-snap and a scrollable container, but I can't work out how to do the same 3d-effect transitions with that setup - I would need some way to tell which item is 'active', but I'm not sure where to begin with that. I suspect it would need to be a JS solution rather than a CSS one?

This specific design and animation style was part of the project brief, so I'd like to keep the appearance as close to the current design as possible.

Thanks in advance for anyone who can point me in the right direction!

CodePen:
https://codepen.io/Carces/pen/qBLRveo

HTML:

```
<body>
  <footer>
    <div class="footer-carousel-container">
      <input
        type="radio"
        name="carousel-slider"
        class="carousel-radio-input"
        id="carousel-input-1"
        checked
      />
      <input
        type="radio"
        name="carousel-slider"
        class="carousel-radio-input"
        id="carousel-input-2"
      />
      <input
        type="radio"
        name="carousel-slider"
        class="carousel-radio-input"
        id="carousel-input-3"
      />
      <div class="carousel-video-cards">
        <label
          class="carousel-card"
          for="carousel-input-1"
          id="carousel-video-1"
        >
          <a id="carousel-link-1" class="carousel-link">
            <img
              src="https://placekitten.com/640/360"
              class="carousel-thumbnail"
            />
          </a>
        </label>

        <label
          class="carousel-card"
          for="carousel-input-2"
          id="carousel-video-2"
        >
          <a id="carousel-link-2" class="carousel-link">
            <img
              src="https://placekitten.com/640/360"
              class="carousel-thumbnail"
            />
          </a>
        </label>

        <label
          class="carousel-card"
          for="carousel-input-3"
          id="carousel-video-3"
        >
          <a id="carousel-link-3" class="carousel-link">
            <img
              src="https://placekitten.com/640/360"
              class="carousel-thumbnail"
            />
          </a>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.footer-carousel-container {
  height: 240px;
  width: 640px;
  text-align: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.footer-carousel-header {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.carousel-thumbnail {
  height: 164px;
  width: 290px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.carousel-card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 46.5%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel-link {
  display: block;
}

#carousel-input-1:checked ~ .carousel-video-cards #carousel-video-3,
#carousel-input-2:checked ~ .carousel-video-cards #carousel-video-1,
#carousel-input-3:checked ~ .carousel-video-cards #carousel-video-2 {
  transform: translatex(-50%) scale(0.8);
  opacity: 0.4;
  z-index: 0;
}

#carousel-input-1:checked ~ .carousel-video-cards #carousel-video-2,
#carousel-input-2:checked ~ .carousel-video-cards #carousel-video-3,
#carousel-input-3:checked ~ .carousel-video-cards #carousel-video-1 {
  transform: translatex(50%) scale(0.8);
  opacity: 0.4;
  z-index: 0;
}

#carousel-input-1:checked ~ .carousel-video-cards #carousel-video-1,
#carousel-input-2:checked ~ .carousel-video-cards #carousel-video-2,
#carousel-input-3:checked ~ .carousel-video-cards #carousel-video-3 {
  transform: translatex(0) scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}

#carousel-input-1:checked ~ .carousel-video-cards #carousel-video-1 img,
#carousel-input-2:checked ~ .carousel-video-cards #carousel-video-2 img,
#carousel-input-3:checked ~ .carousel-video-cards #carousel-video-3 img {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);
}

.carousel-radio-input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
}

.carousel-radio-input:checked {
  background-color: blue;
}

.footer-carousel-controls {
  position: relative;
  top: 244px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
}
```